# IB Api get list of symbols by passing exchange name

Tags: tws, ib-api

I am new to IB API and I want to fetch a list of symbols of a particular exchange type. So basically I will pass exchange/type and receive a list of symbols.

I am not able to find out a relevant method.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible to download a list of symbols on a particular exchange from the TWS API. The closest functionality would be the instrument search which allows you to search for an entry in the database using the symbol or company name:

[symbol search documentation](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/matching_symbols.html)

Other options are to use the Product Listing on the website, or to use the ftp site used for short stock availability:

[website product listing](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1563)

[stock loan availability ftp site](https://ibkr.info/article/2024)

Comment: I see the symbol search documentation but it only gives stock contracts. I see there are other options but I am not getting how to use it because I am very new to IB. If there is any example please share.

Comment: The symbol search function is only for stocks, yes. There is also functionality to pull option chains, but if you're interesting in something like futures, then you could consider pulling information from the website. Though the underlying contracts for futures are actually fairly standard, and its possible to query a list of futures on an underlying symbol from the API also.